# Fetching data from sql table and displaying on screen with react native and js

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, react-native

i just started learning about react native and apk development and i am making an application that is displaying the number of student that are present in a class. currently the text is some random letters where the quantity should be, but i want to fetch the number of records from the table and display it

```
 <ScrollView
          style={styles.mainView}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.mainCont}>
          <View style={{flex: 3}}>
            <Button
              title={(props) => (
                <View style={styles.textView}>
                  <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>
                    MATH CLASS STUDENTS
                  </Text>   
                  <Text style={styles.subtitle}>SAMPLE</Text>
                </View>
              )}
              //   title="MATH CLASS"
              onPress={this.mathObservation}
              buttonStyle={styles.buttonStyle}
              titleStyle={styles.titleStyle}
            />
```

Comment: you need to use a middleware some rest api or soap service to connect to sql and extract  the information then you can consume the api with an http request and get the data on the front end or ui interface!

Comment: @crizcl i have an api that allows for inserting records, however i want to count all the records that are in the table

Comment: you can count the data inside the rest api and return the list and the counter, at the same time and do whatever you want on the react page.

Comment: @crizcl how would i go about doing that?

Comment: you need to change logic inside api to do that! after you insert you can count the table's items and then return the succes on insert and the counter, and how could you do that depends on the stack you are using!